# Inserting one of two classes in div declaration in PHP code

Tags: php, html, css

I need to modify some PHP code. At present it contains a var defined in this way:

```
$someVariable = '<div class="someClass" style="someStyle" ...>...</div>'
```

Depending on the value of a random variable I have to insert either one or the other of two classes into the div in this variable, using code something like this.

```
$random = mt_rand (0,1);
if($random == 0){
    ... class ="extraClass1" ...
}
else {
    ... class ="extraClass2" ...
}
```

The result would be something like:

```
$someVariable = '<div class="someClass" class="extraClassn" style="someStyle" ...>...</div>'
```

I don't know what syntax to use to change $someVariable. Can you please tell me.

Comment: Clarify title

Shows results needed. More careful development of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$random = mt_rand (0,1);
$randomClass = '';

if($random == 0){
    $randomClass = 'class1';
} else {
    $randomClass = 'class2';
}

$someVariable = '<div class="someClass '.$randomClass.'" style="someStyle" ...>...</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$random = mt_rand (0, 1);
if($random == 0){
    $class= 'class1';
} else {
    $class= 'class2';
}

$someVariable = '<div class="'.$class.'" style="someStyle" ...>...</div>';
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

this is highly unrecommended for both security and separation of concerns. But it's definitely doable with your style:

split your variable into 3: one with `'<div class="`, maybe `$head`, a `$classNames` with `'someClass '`, and a `$tail` with `'" style="someStyle" ...>...</div>'`

Now, to add a class, say `otherClass`, just append it to your `$classNames`:

`$classNames .= 'otherClass '`, without forgetting the extra space.

When your variable is finally ready, you can concatenate the other variables to achieve it: `$completeVariable = $head . $classNames . $tail`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$random = mt_rand (0,1);
$class= ($random == 0)?'class1':'class2';
$someVariable = '<div class="'.$class.'" style="someStyle" ...>...</div>';
```